# Prevent description merge of overloaded function style macros

Tags: doxygen

```
/** @file macrooverloadtest.h */

/**
 * abc
 */
#define MYMACRO(ARG1)

/**
 * def
 */
#define MYMACRO(ARG1,ARG2)
```

As you can see, I have an overloaded macro ( from what doxygen is able to see, the real code is one variadic macro and hidden from doxygen ).

When I generate the documentation, it merges the description. So, both `MYMACRO`'s description is "abcdef". How can I stop doxygen from doing that ?